# Calling navigator.javaEnabled() after assigning to a variable

Tags: javascript

I am assigning the javaEnabled() function to a variable like this:

```
var je = navigator.javaEnabled;
```

Now when I try to invoke the function using `je();`, it throws an error in chrome that says

> VM960:1 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)

In Firefox, the error is:

> TypeError: 'javaEnabled' called on an object that does not implement interface Navigator.

Why does it fail like this?

Comment: `je` has the reference for the javaEnabled func. But it is not being called on the correct object. You have to bind this to the `navigator` object like: `let jeb = je.bind(navigator);` Now a call to `jeb()` yields the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call something like `obj.func()`, `func` will be called with `obj` as its `this` value. Firefox complains about an incompatible `this` value. In your case it's either `null` or the global object (normally `window`), depending on context and if you `use strict`. `javaEnabled` needs the `navigator` object, just es `Object.valueOf()` needs `Object`.